Demonstrating benefits of `uid_map` for linux user namespaces?
I am learning about linux user namespaces for the first time.  At present, I am trying to understand the benefits of creating a /proc/[PID]/uid_map and /proc/[PID]/gid_map.  It seems that without these files, a user in a child namespace can still modify files made by the user in the parent namespace.  And all that the /proc/[PID]/uid_map and /proc/[PID]/gid_map does is make the ls command recognize who owns which files.  I am sure I misunderstood the benefits of the uid_map and gid_map files, can someone correct my understanding with an example?
Let me show the simple experiments that I was conducting which led to my statements above, so everyone can see where my headspace is currently at.
I create one terminal with ssh connection to my dev area.  Then I ran these commands, to show my user info, attempt to create a text file from various namespaces, then check file permission details:
me@localhost:~$ id
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=1000(me),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd)
me@localhost:~$
me@localhost:~$ cat 'hello' > test.txt
me@localhost:~$ unshare -U /bin/bash
nobody@localhost:~$
nobody@localhost:~$ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
nobody@localhost:~$
nobody@localhost:~$ ls -lh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody nogroup   12 Dec 10 18:41 test.txt
nobody@localhost:~$
nobody@localhost:~$
nobody@localhost:~$ ls -lh /
total 2.1G
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup    7 Aug 10  2023 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody nogroup 4.0K Dec 10 14:07 boot
...etc...
nobody@localhost:~$ cat 'world' >> test.txt
nobody@localhost:~$ cat test.txt
hello
world

nobody@localhost:~$ cat 'hello' > /test.txt # attempt to write to directory that is NOT owned by nobody@localhost or me@localhost
bash: /test.txt: Permission denied

This taught me a few things:

nobody@localhost is using the system default overflow uid/gid 65534
nobody@localhost CAN edit files made by me@localhost
nobody@localhost CAN NOT edit files made the ubuntu root user (ie. system files in the / directory)
nobody@localhost see files made by me@localhost and files made by the ubuntu root user as nobody@localhost

Next I created a second terminal window with ssh connection to the same dev area as above.  Then I ran these commands to create the uid_map and gid_map:
me@localhost:~$ ps l | grep /bin/bash
0  1000    1585    1263  20   0   8792  5712 do_sel S+   pts/1      0:00 /bin/bash

# then I take the 1585 from above and do this
me@localhost:~$ sudo echo "0 1000 65335" | sudo tee /proc/1585/uid_map
me@localhost:~$ sudo echo "0 1000 65335" | sudo tee /proc/1585/gid_map

Then I return to the first terminal and run these commands to observe the results introduced by uid_map and gid_map:
nobody@localhost:~$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),65534(nogroup)
nobody@localhost:~$ 
nobody@localhost:~$ ls -lh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   12 Dec 10 18:41 test.txt
nobody@localhost:~$ 
nobody@localhost:~$ ls -lh /
total 2.1G
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup    7 Aug 10  2023 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody nogroup 4.0K Dec 10 14:07 boot
...etc...

This taught me a few things:

nobody@localhost now sees files made by me@localhost as being made by a user named root (not to be confused with the ubuntu system root user in the parent namespace)
nobody@localhost continues to see files made by the ubuntu sytem root user as nobody.

Therefore, is the only benefit of using /proc/[pid]/uid_map and /proc/[pid]/gid_map to allow a child namespace to better discern who owns what file when using the ls command?  The uid_map and gid_map don't seem to enforce file permissions by allowing/disallowing file edits based on file ownership.
